# Error while executing SP in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: entity-framework-core

Below is the snapshot of the sample context file I have added.

```
public   class EmployeeDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeDbContext()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<GetCustomer_Result> Customers { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {

                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-38MUAJS;Initial Catalog=Employee;Integrated Security=True;");
            }
        }


        // public async Task<List<GetCustomer_Result>> GetEmployeeByName(string name)
        public List<GetCustomer_Result> GetEmployeeByName(string name)
        {
            var param = new SqlParameter("@Name",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,20);
            param.Value = name;
            //  var students = await Customers.FromSqlRaw<GetCustomer_Result>("GetCustomer @Name", param).ToList<GetCustomer_Result>();
             var students =  Customers.FromSqlRaw<GetCustomer_Result>("exec GetCustomer @Name", param).ToList<GetCustomer_Result>();

            return students;
        }

    }
```

I am calling from main with below code.

```
   EmployeeDbContext dbcontext = new EmployeeDbContext();
            var response = dbcontext.GetEmployeeByName("sachin");
```

I am getting error Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.

Comment: You did not share your `GetCustomer_Result` class, and the object what the stored procedure returns. Isn't there any type mismatch between those two?

Comment: public  class GetCustomer_Result
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: And what are the types coming from the stored procedure? Is is possible that the type of the Id in your stored procedure is not int?